# Vue Laravel передача из одного компонента в другой данных

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Испльзую vue в laravel.
Задача сделать хтмл-теги , которые можно использовать в шаблоне laravel
вот шаблон:

```
<form-search-component >
<div>
    <form-search-out-component />
</div>

<div>
    <tickets-component />
</div>
```

в app.js подключаю так vue `import {createApp} from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js';`

Мне необходимо сделать чтобы в form-search-out-component была кнопка субмит, при нажатии на нею происходил Аякс запрос, который выводил данные в компонент tickets-component

Есть в vue provide/inject - но в них теги компонентов должны иметь дерево - тогда это работает, а если компоненты на одном уровне находятся, то тогда как обмениваться между ними данными?